# Sort a vector where the largest is at the center in r

Tags: r, sorting

I know this is a simple question, but I have searched everywhere and I am pretty sure that there is no answer to my question.

I want to sort a vector where the largest is in the middle and goes to to tails when the values go down.

For example:

```
c( 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
```

I want to have:

```
c(20, 40, 60, 50, 30 ) or c(30, 50, 60, 40, 20 )
```

It does not matter.

Can anyone offer me a quick solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we assume an odd number of elements?

Answer (score 3):

This is much easier to solve if you assume that you have 2n (n is a natural number) distinct observations. Here is one solution:

```
ints = sample.int(100, size = 30, replace = FALSE)
ints_o = ints[order(ints)]
ints_tent = c(ints_o[seq.int(from = 1, to = (length(ints) - 1), by = 2)],
              rev(ints_o[seq.int(from = 2, to = length(ints), by = 2)]))
```

### Edit:

Here is function that deals with both cases:

```
makeTent = function(ints) {
  ints_o = ints[order(ints)]
  if((length(ints) %% 2) == 0) {
    # even number of observations
    ints_tent = c(ints_o[seq.int(from = 1, to = (length(ints) - 1), by = 2)],
      rev(ints_o[seq.int(from = 2, to = length(ints), by = 2)]))
  } else {
    # odd number of observations
    ints_tent = c(ints_o[seq.int(from = 2, to = (length(ints) - 1), by = 2)],
      rev(ints_o[seq.int(from = 1, to = length(ints), by = 2)]))
  }
  return(ints_tent)
}

# test the function
ints_even = sample.int(100, size = 30, replace = FALSE)
ints_odd = sample.int(100, size = 31, replace = FALSE)
makeTent(ints_odd)
makeTent(ints_even)
```

Comment: This is nice by removes the actual maximum. You can also replace `ints_o = ints[order(ints)]` with just `ints_o <- sort(ints)` i guess.

Comment: Maybe `c(ints_o[seq.int(from = 1, to = (length(ints) - 1), by = 2)], max(ints),
  rev(ints_o[seq.int(from = 2, to = length(ints), by = 2)]))`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Does it remove the maximum? Under my even number of observations assumption, it does not.

Comment: OP doesn't have even number of observations though. You could make a function with a condition I guess.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah, actually this scales to both cases -- whether the first sequence starts with one or two depends on whether we have an odd or even number of observations.